# ajax cross domain fetch xml

Tags: xml, ajax, cross-domain

I'm sure this question has been asked before. there might be no way around it. I just want to try my luck.

so can I do a crossdomain ajax call to get xml in this way? if there is how?

```
| client  |<--->| Server |
    ^
    |
    |
    ------>| other domain (such as toutube) |
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend "bouncing" it off of a local .php/.asp/.whatever file and have it retrieve the data. In addition to being fully compliant, it also helps in adding a caching layer should you so desire.

Something like:

/ajax/load.php?url=

Of course, you're going to most likely want to lock it down. No need to be used as a tool of evil.